# How to copy view from MS SQL to PGSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a MS SQL Server running in a different country (hence VPN, hence long round trip delay) and delveloping a PowerQuery model on a view located on that MS SQL Server.
Everytime I change something in the model, it reloads the view which is consuming a lot of time.
I'd like to:

1. setup a local PostGreSQL Server on my Mac (done already)
2. mirror the MS SQL View data into a PostgreSQL Database
3. connect the powerQuery to the local PostgreSQL Server (easy)

I'm struggling with "2", mirror the content of a view into the PostgreSQL server without using direct SQL (TCP1433) which I cannot use.

How can I mirror the data to the PostgreSQL Server using ODBC only?

BTW: I have no direct access to the MS SQL Server apart from the ODBC connection

EDIT: If required, I can also install a MS SQL Express Edition if that helps in any way. Thanks

Comment: `SELECT` the view into a CSV file locally on SSMS, and then load that CSV directly into Postgres.

Comment: It's THAT easy? stupid me .... will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Not at all a stupid question.  There may be a way to directly transfer but I wouldn't expect it to be easy.  But CSV is a no brainer.

Comment: When using csv with postgres, it is my experience that you need to be very careful with date formats, if there are dates in the view you are importing.

Comment: Man this is such a compound question with obvious good intentions I'm not sure how to answer it. Is the data read-only? Can you migrate entirely to PostgreSQL (is that what you're after). What role with SQL Server play with this?

Comment: when you say "mirror the MS SQL View data into a PostgreSQL Database" are you saying the one-time output of the view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mirror the content of the view to a PGSQL. But never mind, I was able to do it with a local SQL express installation very easily.